# Need help to create a new Spreadsheet in objective-c

Tags: ios, google-sheets-api

Trying to use the new v4 of the sheets API to create a sheet with the following code

```
- (void)createSpreadsheet {
NSString *baseUrl = @"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets";

GTLObject *newSpreadsheet = [[GTLObject alloc] init];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"title", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"APIv4 Test", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

[newSpreadsheet setJSONValue:jsonDict forKey:@"properties"];
//[newSpreadsheet setJSON:jsonDict];

[self.service fetchObjectByInsertingObject:newSpreadsheet forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]
                        delegate:self
               didFinishSelector:@selector(displaySheetIDWithServiceTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

}

The error I get is:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. 
(Client project not found.  Please pass a valid project.)
```

I guess there is something wrong with my JSON representation? Or am I using the wrong method call to create a new spreadsheet?

If I try and use `fetchObjectByUpdatingObject` I get a 404 not found error which makes sense since it doesn't exist yet.

I know I can do it with the Drive API but would prefer to use the new v4 function.

Comment: did you already enable the Sheets API in your Developer console?

Comment: Hi @KENdi, yeah I installed the API using cocoa pods just like the quickstart.  Was able to successfully run the quickstart but documentation seems to be a bit thin regarding this new create method.  I would have thought it would be similar to the GData API for creating a new sheet where you just need to provide the sheet name and the method call is `fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:`

Comment: ok @KENdi after reading your comment again I realise my mistake.  No I hadn't enabled the API in the developer console.  Weird because the quickstart makes no mention of having to do that in fact it says it does it automatically.  Anyway after enabling it my code works successfully.  Thank you so much I should have picked that up myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Sheets API in your Developer console